# How to make Flutter HTTP partial (range) request?

Tags: flutter, dart

#### Code

I have this `main.dart` Flutter code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as $http;

Future main() async {
  await hit();
}

Future hit() async {
  const url = 'https://data.wikibulary.com/data/plain/index/en/0.bin';
  const len = 10000024;
  final resp = await $http.get(url, headers: {
    'range': 'bytes = ${len - 1}-${len - 1}',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  });
  final headers = resp.headers.entries.fold('', (r, i) => '$r\n${i.key}: ${i.value}');
  print('length: ${resp.bodyBytes.length}\n-------------\nheaders:\n$headers');
}
```

#### Problem

Range request header is ignored for Windows desktop and Android. For Flutter Web it works great.

#### Response headers for all three platforms:

WEB:

```
statusCode: 206
length: 1
-----------
cache-control: public, max-age=86400000
content-length: 1
content-type: application/octet-stream
date: Sat, 09 Jan 2021 11:12:22 GMT
etag: 0x8D8B4749CC587E6
last-modified: Sat, 09 Jan 2021 08:00:21 GMT
```

WINDOWS:

```
statusCode: 200
length: 10000024
-----------
connection: keep-alive
last-modified: Sat, 09 Jan 2021 08:00:21 GMT
cache-control: public, max-age=86400000
access-control-allow-origin: *
date: Sat, 09 Jan 2021 11:09:00 GMT
vary: Accept-Encoding
age: 6367
content-type: application/octet-stream
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 10000024
etag: 0x8D8B4749CC587E6
```

ANDROID EMULATOR:

```
I/flutter ( 5528): statusCode: 200
I/flutter ( 5528): length: 10000024
I/flutter ( 5528): -----------
I/flutter ( 5528):
I/flutter ( 5528): connection: keep-alive
I/flutter ( 5528): last-modified: Sat, 09 Jan 2021 08:00:21 GMT
I/flutter ( 5528): cache-control: public, max-age=86400000
I/flutter ( 5528): access-control-allow-origin: *
I/flutter ( 5528): date: Sat, 09 Jan 2021 11:10:42 GMT
I/flutter ( 5528): vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: and what are raw request headers sent for all those cases? i think you can see them with `devtools`

Comment: No headers in devtools (for Windows Desktop). It shows "Duration: Pending" and "End time: Pending".
For Web (from Chrome): accept: */*; accept-encoding: identity; cache-control: no-cache; origin: http://localhost:63793; range: bytes=10000023-10000023; referer: http://localhost:63793/

Comment: Of course, but devtools don't show them for me.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, space char matter in `'bytes = ${len - 1}-${len - 1}'`

Correct code is:

```
final resp = await $http.get(url, headers: {
  'range': 'bytes=${len - 1}-${len - 1}',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
});
```